# xcode swift Storyboard Reference not woking

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I did search google, and same trying.
but not working... i try img upload!
why error ...?

trying href : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-staying-organized-with-storyboard-references--cms-24226

another storyboards connect... and tab move controllers

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the minimum iOS version you're building for?

Comment: add png file. and maybe i think iOS 8.0

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772990/refactored-storyboard-fails-to-compile-xcode7

Answer (score 1):

Storyboard references only work on iOS 9 and up. Your target is 8.0. Try changing your target to 9.0 and see if it starts working.